# How to send GET request to Azure FHIR from Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to send GET request to Azure API for FHIR using Spring Boot.
I have created an application having permission as **"FHIR Data Contributor"**, and have its `client-id`, `tenant-id` and `client-secret-value`.
I have written the code below to get the **access_token**. It is returning the access_token, but how do I make use of the token and send GET request to FHIR ?

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient;


@RestController
public class HelloController {
    
    @GetMapping("/token")
    @ResponseBody
    public String token(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("graph") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) { 
        String accessToken=client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        return accessToken; 
    }
    
    
}
```

The application.yml contains:

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: XXXXXXX-xxxxx-XXXXXXXX
    client-id: XXXXXXX-xxxxx-XXXXXXXX
    client-secret: XXXXXXX-xxxxx-XXXXXXXX
    authorization-clients:
      graph:
        scopes: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

I am able to do all this using Postman.